# Calling HTML Help from command prompt with keyword

Tags: command-prompt, chm

I have to call html help - chm files, that is - from a command prompt. i know how to call the file:

```
hh "mk:@MSITStore:C:\temp\damatomodule.chm"
```

I even know how to go to a specific page

```
hh "mk:@MSITStore:C:\temp\damatomodule.chm::/page/topic.htm"
```

What I have to do is go to a specific keyword without knowing the path and name of the page. This is about a contect sensitive help system in a legacy editor that allows to add third party programs.

How would I pass a parameter $curtoken that contains the word that is to be searched for in the chm file to above command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK you can't do this with hh.exe - but KeyHH.exe is an option.

KeyHH.EXE is a free program from KeyWorks Software, written by Ralph Walden. KeyHH.EXE supports many more command line options then HH.EXE. 
You can get more information about KeyHH.EXE from the KeyWorks web site at http://keyworks.helpmvp.com/.

Click KeyHH 1.1, search for the download link (scroll down) and install.
From the command line call:

```
         KeyHH.exe -MyHelp -#klink "windmill" "D:\_working\CHM-example.chm"
```

Comment: is it possible to convert CHM from HTML in windows command line?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.help-info.de/en/Help_Info_HTMLHelp/hh_command.htm#Compile

Comment: It's better to ask a new question. Don't ask in comments.

Comment: I got it, able to generate chm from the command line using hhp file, but how i can generate hhp file from command line, here HHp file I used was already generated by HTML workshop tool.